# Hide file extensions from tab labels in PhpStorm

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I use PhpStorm for a project that has some very lengthy class names. As a result, not many files can fit in the tab bar above the editor before they get truncated and I have to go into the dropdown.

I was thinking, I could probably at least slightly decrease the impact of this issue if I could get PhpStorm to hide the extensions from the end of the file names (the icons in the tabs make them redundant anyway). Does anyone know a way to make PhpStorm do this? Any help is much appreciated!

Here's a screenshot, showing the tab bar I'm talking about (it's got a big red box around it), and showing what I want to change (I striked through the file extensions).[image: screenshot of PhpStorm demonstrating what I want]

Comment: Underrated question.  This was very useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it in the settings:

`File`, `Settings`, Label `IDE Settings`, `Editor`, `Editor Tabs`, check `Hide file extensions in editor tabs`.

Comment: Perfect, this solves it; muchos gracias. However, on my version of PhpStorm (8.0.3) the path I followed was slightly different: `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `General` > `Editor Tabs` > check `Hide file extension in editor tabs`. Of course, you could also just open `File` > `Settings` and search for "hide file extension in editor tabs" to get it.

Comment: Sorry for that, I am using PHPStorm 7.4.1 but indeed you should find it in the settings search bar. Glad I could help you!

Comment: Not a problem, just figured I ought to document it for the next person who comes along. :) Thanks again!